# Creating a new vector in Matlab with the help of a for-loop

Tags: matlab

Given the vector `x`, I would like to create a vector `u0` componentwise by checking the components of `x`. Since only `0 <= 0 < 1` is true, and since `0` is the first component of `x`, the new vector `u0` should actually look like `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, but instead, Matlab gives me a vector that only contains `0`. What have I done wrong?

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
u0 = [];

for i = 1:8
  if (0 <= x(i) < 1)
    u0(i) = 1;
  else
    u0(i) = 0;
  end
end
```

Comment: `0 <= x(i) < 1` is equivalent to `(0 <= x(i)) < 1`. Since the expression in parentheses is always `true` for your input, `true < 1` always evaluates to `false` - which is why you're getting zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if conditional is not correct. You need to check on it. You have to proceed like below.

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
u0 = zeros(size(x));

for i = 1:8
    if x(i) >= 0 && x(i)<1
        u0(i) = 1;
    else
        u0(i) = 0;
    end
end
```

Also, you can obtain the task in a single line, using the below:

```
u1 = zeros(size(x)) ;
u1(x>=0 & x<1) = 1 ;
```

Comment: Thanks! You're first code gives the error "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers
or logicals."

Comment: It is not throwing error in MATLAB 2015a..what version are you on?

Comment: My Matlab version is 2016b.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I tried to take a look at x(0), which is, of course, not existing. The for-loop has to go from 1:9 in this case.